# jquery: how to get the text before and after a " - " with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a label, which contains text. I need to get the two text elements which are separated by " - ". How can I do this with regular expressions in jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advise to use split rather than a regular expression. You can get both elements by using `string.split(" - ");`. This will return a string array with the elements split at the " - ".

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need regex?

```
var title = "Hello - World!";
var parts = title.split(' - ');
alert(parts[0] + '\n' + parts[1]);
```

Unless I'm missing something, regex is not necessary and just induces unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Why use a regex?

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/BgKFR/)

```
var array = $('label').map(function(){
    return this.innerHTML.split('-');
}).get();
```

**Markup**

```
<label>test-test2</label>
<label>test1-test3</label>
```

This will produce an array of the individual text elements. See console output in fiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mySplitResult = $('#myLabel').val().split("-");
```

`mySplitResult[0]` will contain the first bit
and 
`mySplitResult[1]` will contain the second bit.